# Почему не работает JList (java) в этом коде?

Tags: java, list

Есть такой код.

```
package Journal;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

class Okno extends JFrame {
    ImageIcon iconS = new ImageIcon("addS.png");
    ImageIcon iconM = new ImageIcon("addM.png");
    public JList label;
    JButton sbtn;
    JButton mbtn;

    public Okno() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        Container cont = getContentPane();
        cont.add(panel);
        setSize(745, 610);
        setTitle("Electronic Journal 3");
        panel.setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setFocusable(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        label = new JList();
        label.setBounds(10, 10, 600, 550);
        label.setBackground(Color.white);
        label.setVisible(true);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        panel.add(label);
        String s[] = new String[1];
        s[0]="Vasa Petrov";
        label = new JList(s);
        sbtn = new JButton();
        sbtn.setBounds(625, 10, 100, 100);
        sbtn.setVisible(true);
        sbtn.setIcon(iconS);
        panel.add(sbtn);
        mbtn = new JButton();
        mbtn.setBounds(625, 120, 100, 440);
        mbtn.setVisible(true);
        mbtn.setIcon(iconM);
        mbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        panel.add(mbtn);
    }
}
```

Всё работает, но JList не работает. Он виден, но не выводит информацию(просто белый квадрат).
Что делаю неправильно?
[image: Картинка окна]

Comment: а где код который открывает это окно?

Answer (score 0):

Вы создаете 2 JList - пустой добавляете на форму, а тот что с данными не добавляете. Поэтому у вас ничего нет.

```
// первый список
label = new JList();
label.setBounds(10, 10, 600, 550);
label.setBackground(Color.white);
label.setVisible(true);
label.setOpaque(true);
// добавили первый список на форму
panel.add(label);
String s[] = new String[1];
s[0] = "Vasa Petrov";
// второй список
label = new JList(s);
sbtn = new JButton("1");
```

Вот так будет работать

```
public Okno() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    Container cont = getContentPane();
    cont.add(panel);
    setSize(745, 610);
    setTitle("Electronic Journal 3");
    panel.setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setFocusable(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    label = new JList(new String[] {"Vasa Petrov"});
    label.setBounds(10, 10, 600, 550);
    label.setBackground(Color.white);
    label.setVisible(true);
    label.setOpaque(true);
    panel.add(label);
    sbtn = new JButton("1");
    sbtn.setBounds(625, 10, 100, 100);
    sbtn.setVisible(true);
    panel.add(sbtn);
    mbtn = new JButton("2");
    mbtn.setBounds(625, 120, 100, 440);
    mbtn.setVisible(true);
    mbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    panel.add(mbtn);
}
```